# Positive and Negative Real numbers

Tags: proof-writing

I stumbled upon this question on Yahoo answers [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120513063606AA257aQ) :

> Prove that for every positive real number x, l/x is also a positive real number.?

Answering to the question is [now] closed, but I was thinking about the answer, when I sketched this argument below, but am not sure if am right, and whether this could be a part of the required proof (or whether this is a mere echo of obvious statements?)

if $p$ is positive real number then this is true:

$p \ge 0 \implies |p| - p = 0$

A similar argument for negative number $n$ would be:

$n \lt 0 \implies |n| - n = 2|n|$

With the above truths, I can then say:

If $x \ge 0$ then ${1 \over x} \ge 0$ since 
$|{1 \over x} | - {1 \over x} = {0 \over x} = 0$

Is this right?

Comment: What is $a$????  Do you mean $|n| - n = 2|n|$?  And, how do you know $\left|\frac{1}{x}\right| - \frac{1}{x} = 0$ if you don't know that $\frac{1}{x}$ is positive?  You're assuming what you want to prove.  If you know properties of absolute value, then since you already know $x$ is positive and thus $|x| = x$, we have $\left|\frac{1}{x}\right| = \frac{|1|}{|x|} = \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: I guess he meant $|n|-n=2|n|$ for $n<0$.

Comment: @Graphth, sorry `a` was supposed to be `n`. corrected that (typo)

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps what you are doing could work but there are key details missing.  We don't know that $\frac{1}{x}$ is positive, that's what we're trying to prove.  So, to say that $\left|\frac{1}{x}\right| - \frac{1}{x} = 0$, which is your definition of $\frac{1}{x}$ being positive, with no other justification, is assuming what you want to prove.

But, if you are allowed to use properties of absolute value, you get
$$\left|\frac{1}{x}\right| = \frac{|1|}{|x|} = \frac{1}{x},$$
which proves that little step, since we already know $x$ is positive and thus $|x| = x$.

Answer (score 0):

What about this: x . 1/x = 1, so x and 1/x must have the same sign.

Comment: note that this would hold even for negative $x$. Our task is to prove $1 \over x$ as positive.

Comment: yes, but only when x is positive